# Check if argument (tuple) is in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I'm really struggling on unpacking and iterating over the tuples in this dictionary.  Essentially, the function takes a two coordinate position (Wx, Wy) and checks to see if it is in one of the tuples located in either list, in the dictionary, bonuses.  I feel like I'm overthinking it, or am just way off.

Thanks :)

```
bonuses = {1: [(3,3)], 2: [(1, 0), (0, 3), (2, 4), (5, 2)]}

def find_bonus(pos):
""" Check if position is valid"""

    bonus_info = dict.values(bonuses)

    for (Wx, Wy) in pos:
        if (Wx, Wy) in tuple(bonus_info):
            return pos
    else:
    return False
```

Comment: This will be painfully slow for many/long lists in the `dict`.  You need another structure (maybe a `set` of all the tuples) if you plan to search for many positions.

Answer (score 2):

You can compare tuple to tuple directly:

1- iterate over the values of the dictionary.
2- check if `pos` is in the values, and return `True` if it is
3- if pos was not found anywhere, return `False`

```
bonuses = {1: [(3,3)], 2: [(1, 0), (0, 3), (2, 4), (5, 2)]}

def find_bonus(pos):
""" Check if position is valid"""

    for valid_pos in bonuses.values():
        if pos in valid_pos:
            return pos   # <-- or return True, depending if pos can ever evaluate at False.
    return False
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`itertools.chain()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) :

```
from itertools import chain

def find_bonus(pos):
    return pos if pos in chain(*bonuses.values()) else False
```

Demo:

```
>>> bonuses = {1: [(3,3)], 2: [(1, 0), (0, 3), (2, 4), (5, 2)]}
>>> find_bonus((100,10))
False
>>> find_bonus((10,10))
False
>>> find_bonus((1,0))
(1, 0)
>>> find_bonus((3,3))
(3, 3)
>>> find_bonus((5,2))
(5, 2)
```

This works because `chain()`, when combined with the `*` unpacking operator applied to `bonuses.values()`, effectively flattens the dictionary's values into a single list for which membership can easily be tested with `in`.

Your function can be simplified further if you have it return a boolean:

```
def find_bonus(pos):
    return pos in chain(*bonuses.values())
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just do this instead. (Assuming pos is a single tuple)

```
bonus_info = set(i for i in j for j in bonuses.values())
def find_bonus(pos):
    if pos in bonus_info:
        return pos
    else:
        return None
```